# How to concatenate 2 fields in WFFM and assign them to one field before form submission?

Tags: wffm

I'm using the [International Telephone Input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) jQuery plugin with a WFFM (Web Form for Marketers) to have a field like this:
[image]

To integrate the js plugin, a custom `SingleLineText` was created.

But the issue here is that, this field will take only the local phone number without the country code.

My question is, how to concatenate the country code with the local phone number and assign the value to the custom field when a user submits the form?

Answer (score 1):

I did not use this plugin before but my guess you can bind onchange event and update the input or a use a hidden one. something like:

$("#phone").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
  // do something with countryData
});